# Error: Conversion from string to type Integer is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to run my code in sql but its keeps saying this message

> "Conversion from string to type Integer is not valid"

Any advice?

```
MysqlConn = New SqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=SABAHALI-SHEIKH;Initial Catalog=md_1103763;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim READER As SqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from md_1103763.dbo.customer"
            COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            While READER.Read
                Dim fName = READER.GetString("firstname")
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(fName)
            End While

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()


        End Try
```

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: i reckon its this line Dim fName = READER.GetString("firstname")

Comment: Please show the full excetpion

Comment: If you only want the `firstname` column, it would be better to write `SELECT [firstname] FROM md_1103763.dbo.customer`, then you can use `READER.GetString(0)`.

Comment: thanks pal it worked, im also stuck on this code, can u help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043701/specified-cast-is-not-available

Answer (score 0):

the source of your error is

```
    Dim fName = READER.GetString("firstname")
```

[GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1.) method takes int as parameter and not string. You are passing string to it. I would recommend that you use column index. the best way to do this is captured in Andrew Morton's comment

Comment: can u help me on this code, click the link, as ive posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043701/specified-cast-is-not-available

Comment: the second answer there is what i was suggesting. its along the line what@Andrew Morton's comment suggest

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove the GetString().
So it would be this...
Dim fName = READER("firstname ")