# Combo box joining two tables from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to show 2 tables from a SQL Server database, but nothing is displayed

Please help!!!!!!!

```
MysqlConn = New SqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=SABAHALI-SHEIKH;Initial Catalog=md_1103763;Integrated Security=True"
Dim READER As SqlDataReader

Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT [customerID], [firstname], [surname], [contactnumber], [emailaddress] FROM md_1103763.dbo.customer where firstname='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        Query = "SELECT [bookingID], [pickupaddress], [destinationaddress], [datebooked], [timebooked] FROM md_1103763.dbo.booking where bookingID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            TextBox1.Text = READER.GetInt32(READER.GetOrdinal("customerID"))
            TextBox2.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("firstname"))
            TextBox3.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("surname"))
            TextBox4.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("contactnumber"))
            TextBox5.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("emailaddress"))

            TextBox8.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("bookingID"))
            TextBox6.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("pickupaddress"))
            TextBox7.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("destinationaddress"))
            DateTimePicker1.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("datebooked"))
            DateTimePicker2.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("timebooked"))

        End While

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()


    End Try
```

Comment: You are resetting the Query variable and executing the second SQL string. The first one doesn't get executed. You need to either join the two together using SQL or execute each one separately.

Comment: how do i go about executing each one separately

Comment: Are both the customer firstname and the booking bookingID the same? You are using the same value in the condition of your SQL statements.

Comment: no, there not the same

Comment: Comment out the second query line and see if it returns any results.

Comment: yes just did that, but when i click on the combobox, the customers information is shown, but a message pops up which says bookingID, is is because i need to specify the column names in the booking table

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This with change 
this code

```
MysqlConn = New SqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=SABAHALI-SHEIKH;Initial Catalog=md_1103763;Integrated Security=True"
Dim READER As SqlDataReader

Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT md_1103763.dbo.customer.customerID, md_1103763.dbo.customer.firstname, md_1103763.dbo.customer.surname,"&"md_1103763.dbo.customer.contactnumber, md_1103763.dbo.customer.emailaddress,"&
        "md_1103763.dbo.booking.bookingID, md_1103763.dbo.booking.pickupaddress, md_1103763.dbo.booking.destinationaddress," &
        "md_1103763.dbo.booking.datebooked, md_1103763.dbo.booking.timebooked FROM md_1103763.dbo.customer,md_1103763.dbo.booking "&
        " where firstname='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'" +" And bookingID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

        COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            TextBox1.Text = READER.GetInt32(READER.GetOrdinal("customerID"))
            TextBox2.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("firstname"))
            TextBox3.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("surname"))
            TextBox4.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("contactnumber"))
            TextBox5.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("emailaddress"))

            TextBox8.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("bookingID"))
            TextBox6.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("pickupaddress"))
            TextBox7.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("destinationaddress"))
            DateTimePicker1.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("datebooked"))
            DateTimePicker2.Text = READER.GetString(READER.GetOrdinal("timebooked"))

        End While

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()


    End Try
```

Comment: It says conversion failed when converting the varchar value ‘roberta’ to data type int. by the way roberta is the customers name